# How to test pre/post commit scripts in git?

Tags: python, git, githooks, git-commit

I've created a git post-commit hook in python and made a file executable and placed it into .git/post-commit.

It works when I run it via Python. Now I want test it locally in git. How can I do that?  I can't make a commit to git locally from my computer in an easy way, right?

Should I copy the hook file to my server and make test commits to test it? Is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't make a commit to git locally from my computer in an easy way, right?

You need to differentiate between **pushing** a branch to a server, which may require some configuration, and simply **creating** a commit, which can be as easy as running a command:

```
$ git commit --allow-empty -m "Testing my hook"
```

Comment: does creating a commit without pushing trigger my local git pre- or post-commit script ?

Comment: @Oaemirami yes - committing and pushing are too different things. See the exact details at https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks.

Answer (score 0):

pre-commit and post-commit hooks are run locally on commit (see https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks ), not on push (push is what transfers your local commits to the server).

To test a hook I would create a test branch, and make several test commits there with whatever content you want. After the hook is ready, you can delete that branch. Until you do a push, everything is local.

Also if you output something from the hook script, that will be visible in the terminal when you do a commit. This is useful for debugging.

For executing the code on the server you should use "Server-Side Hooks" ([see at the bottom of this page](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks), also [documented here](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks)).

Comment: they run locally? then what git hook should I use that'll trigger **on a server** when I push my code to a repo?

Comment: For the server side use "Server-Side Hooks" like "post-receive". I've updated the answer with the links.

Comment: for a server-side hook, will working directory for a hook script be `/home/my_user/my_project/.git/`?

Comment: The scripts are inside ".git/hooks" (or just "hooks" for a "bare" repo) and has to be executable. Please read https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Comment: I know. My question was **will working directory for a hook script be /home/my_user/my_project/.git/** ? or  **/home/my_user/my_project/**? not a directory where I save it, but the working one

Comment: Ah, I see. It depends, I actually use $GIT_DIR in my scripts. Better ask a new question and describe your server-side setup.

Comment: i'm asking here: what's $GIT_DIR  in my case?

Comment: It depends on your server-side setup. You can print it to test.